# Download 280 GB of Million Song Dataset

Tags: hadoop, download, bigdata

I'd like to download the complete Million Song Dataset available at Infochimps. I am not using AWS and have a cluster provided by my University that I would like to download the data to. I am currently using wget but that will take me ages to download. Is there a better way to download the data?

Also is there a way to download the data directly to the Hadoop File System instead of downloading first to local filesystem and then using -copyFromLocal to copy to HDFS?

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way, in my view, would be to use a data aggregation tool like [Flume](http://flume.apache.org/) or [Chukwa](http://incubator.apache.org/chukwa/). Both of these tools allows us to aggregate huge amounts of data in a distributed and reliable manner. Not only this, these tools will allow you to ingest the data directly into your Hadoop cluster. You might have to do some work though, like writing your custom source that will pull data from the source into your cluster.

HTH

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into Flume and Chukwa.